# How can I transfer FTP to FTP?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

How to transfer ftp to ftp ?
any direct ftp softwares to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can transfer files between FTP servers without having to act as a proxy for the data.

It's called *FXP* and ftp server (many do) have to support it. You can read about FXP [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) and lftp (linux) and coreftp, flashfxp etc on windows.. Are clients you could
use for FTP-FXP.

Comment: Careful with fxp- it should have been disabled by default and should be disabled when you are done as there are known exploits for fxp

Comment: OMG... can you tell possible exploits with it ?

Comment: @JimB: if he can modify the server, then the whole question is kind of pointless, since he could install any kind of program to do this transfer anyway.

Comment: @Lohoris- which is why it's disabled by default, a simple search for FXP can should what can be done with it but I have no desire to post them here.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day we would use something called [Kermit](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ck80.html).  Looks like it still exists.  Give it a look it will certainly do what you need

Answer (score 0):

If I recall the RFCs on the FTP protocol, this was what PASSIVE mode ftp was all about.  From a single control station, you open the two connections and then tell them to pass data between them directly.  I have seen this feature rarely used in this capacity however.

Using a simple FTP client you can easily set this up.